# Files not showing up in Shared with Me on OneDrive for Business

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I have SharePoint 2016 On-Prem. Documents that have been Shared with me do not show up in my OneDrive for Business area called "Shared with Me".  Instead it only displays "No one is sharing a document with you at this time."

I have run a full crawl, still nothing.  Any ideas?

Bismarck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable RSI? It must be enabled first, followed by a crawl.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business#EnableRSIcache

Comment: If the answer helped you, then please mark as such, so that others may be assisted.